# How to show values form custome object in iphone app

Tags: iphone, nsarray

I have custom object and I have stored my values in Array. but I am bit stuck to show objects values form array. My code definition is here.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 {
Person *myPerson = [[Person alloc] init];
myPerson.name = @"Brian";
myPerson.age = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:23];     
[myArray addObject:myPerson];       
[myPerson release];         
}
```

Now I want to show all 20 values which is stored in Array (name and age of person). 
How will I show that values?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)

        
        Person *myPerson = [[Person alloc] init];

        
        myPerson=[facebook_wallDataArray objectAtIndex:i];
        
        NSLog(@" message string %@", myPerson.name);
    }   this is the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways of showing the customers depending on what you want.

**1. Print to the console**

If you just want to print them out to the console, you can use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Person *thisPerson = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@ has an age of %d", thisPerson.name, thisPerson.age);
}
```

additionally, you can use Fast Enumerators to neaten things up:

```
for (Person *thisPerson in myArray) 
{
    NSLog(@"%@ has an age of %d", thisPerson.name, thisPerson.age);
}
```

**2. Showing in a table view**

You'll need a `UITableView` with an instance of `UITableViewController` that conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

This tutorial gives you an excellent walkthrough:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/

If neither of these solutions suits, please provide more information about what you're trying to achieve.